# How can I grep a keyword which contain underscore?

Tags: bash

I am currently searching some keyword something like

`find -type f | xargs -grep -i -w 'weblogic_*'`

But it show all the keyword match with `weblogic` instead of `weblogic_`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`grep` uses *regular expressions*, not globs (wildcard expressions).

In regular expressions, `*` is a quantifier that *relates to the previous character or expression*. Thus, `_*` is saying: *zero or more* instances of `_`, so NO `_` will be matched as well.

You probably want:

```
'weblogic_.*'
```

which states that any (`.`) character may follow the `_` zero or more times.

Note, however, that ending your regex in `_.*` partially contradicts `grep`'s `-w` flag in that it will now only match the *beginning* of your regex on a word boundary.

If you wanted to be more explicit about this, you could use the word-boundary assertion `\b` and drop the `-w` option:

```
'\bweblogic_'
```

As you can see, this allows you to omit the `.*`, as `grep` performs *substring* matching by default, and you needn't match the remainder of the line if it is not of interest.

Also, there is no need for `xargs`: it is simpler and more efficient to use `find`'s `-exec` primary, which has `xargs` built in, so to speak:

```
 find . -type f -exec grep -i '\bweblogic_' {} +
```

`{}` represents the list of input filenames and `+` specifies that as many input filenames as possible should be passed at once - as with `xargs`.

Finally, if your `grep` version supports the `-R` option, you can make do without `find` altogether and simply let grep process all files recursively:

```
 grep -R -i '\bweblogic_' .
```

Answer (score 4):

When you use the pattern `weblogic_*`, it means look for `weblogic` followed by zero or more occurrences of `_`.

You can change it to use the pattern `weblogic_.*` if you want to avoid matching `weblogic` that is not followed by a `_`.

```
find -type f | xargs -grep -i -w 'weblogic_.*'
```

should work.

Comment: However it will break with files containing newlines. Please see this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020

Answer (score 4):

Try without regex

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -i 'weblogic_'
```

Answer (score 1):

simply use this :

```
grep -i '^weblogic_.*'
```